# Databases that support SELECT * EXCEPT/REPLACE?

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

BigQuery supports the following notation for SQL:

```
select_list:
    { select_all | select_expression } [, ...]

select_all:
    [ expression. ]*
    [ EXCEPT ( column_name [, ...] ) ]
    [ REPLACE ( expression [ AS ] column_name [, ...] ) ]
```

Meaning something like the following can be done:

```
SELECT * EXCEPT (id, socialSecurity)
```

And some other small things.

Do any databases support this? I find the `EXCEPT` clause useful, and although I know how to use the `REPLACE` I've never found an actual practical use case for that ever. Are there ever any practical uses of that (i.e., aside from made up examples in the docs)?

Comment: i think, there are plenty examples of practical use of `select * except/replace` here on SO for bigquery tag :o) as an example - i just recently answered question with `select * except` involved - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73513929/5221944

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant -- thanks, is that a BigQuery-specific extension, or have you seen that in any other databases?

Comment: just very few from quick search - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58837661/5221944, https://stackoverflow.com/a/42847416/5221944, https://stackoverflow.com/a/39297110/5221944 ...   
As of use in other databases - not sure :o(

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant and yes I think `SELECT * EXCEPT` is great! I've just never had the use of using `* REPLACE`

Comment: What are you looking for in an answer? "Do any databases support this?", apparently bigquery does, at least. "Are there ever any practical uses of that", why does it matter?

Comment: @HoneyBadger right, do you know of any others that support it? That was my main question.